# can we use hiphop compiled code in production server without source code?

Tags: php, hiphop

we have a php based product, some of our customers ask for host the source on there server but for source code security we are not doing such hosting. my question is, can we host a hiphop compiled files on customer`s server.

steps in my mind.

1. we will compile the source php in our server
2. collect the compiled files from server
3. host the compiled files on customers server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HipHop (now called HPHPc) converts PHP code into C++ code which is compiled into a stand-alone binary which is run on a server natively. Source code need not be present.